# Minimum value of $4r + 5 r^2$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

We can say by quadratic formula that min value will occur at $r=-2/5$.

However by AM-GM inequality, Min value of function will be achieved when $4r=5r^2$ (equality sign holds when each term is equal to other).

From here $r=4/5$

Where am I going conceptually wrong?

Comment: Beware of the condition you need to apply AM-GM inequality (i.e that $a,b>0$).

Comment: AM/GM is about positive numbers, isn't it?

Comment: Complete the square, and if you don't know how, learn it.

Comment: I know about completing the square.

Comment: So is there no way I can apply am GM here ?

Comment: What if I restrict values of r to positive values ?

Comment: @Anmol Agarwal For positive $r$ the minimum does not exist. For non-negative $r$ the minimum is $0$.

Comment: I mean that for y =f(r) .What can be the least value y can attain for all positive r ? In that case will r be 4/5 ?

Comment: Is there any link , site where conditions regarding am GM inequality  are mentioned ?

Answer (score 1):

$$4r+5r^2=5\left(r^2+\frac{4}{5}r\right)=5\left(r+\frac{2}{5}\right)^2-\frac{4}{5}\geq-\frac{4}{5}.$$
The equality occurs for $r=-\frac{2}{5}$, which says that $-\frac{4}{5}$ is a minimal value.

Comment: Exemplified as my comment has suggested ... being typed at the same time  - a good answer.